# Setting Up Simple Tensorflow Linear Regression Returning NaN Values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-regression

I'm new to Tensorflow and I want to know why I'm getting nan values for cost, W and b at each epoch? I'm setting up a traffic game and I'd like to train a model to be able to predict what the best duration of a green light would be, based on previous rewards and previous green light durations. I tried following [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-regression-using-tensorflow/) to set it up, but doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? This could should replicate the issue I'm having, and I've added in lots of prints to be able to help someone more experienced than I. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='once', category=FutureWarning) # future warnings annoy me

# add in a couple of rewards and light durations
current_reward = [-1000,-900,-950]
current_green = [10,12,12]

current_reward = np.array(current_reward)
current_green = np.array(current_green)

# Pass in reward and green_light
def green_light_duration_new(current_reward, current_green):
    # Predicting the best light duration based on previous rewards.
    # predict the best duration based on previous step's reward value, using simple linear regression model
    x = current_reward
    y = current_green
    n = len(x)
    # Plot of Training Data  
    plt.scatter(x, y) 
    plt.xlabel('Reward') 
    plt.ylabel('Green Light Duration') 
    plt.title("Training Data") 
    plt.show() 

    X = tf.placeholder("float") 
    Y = tf.placeholder("float") 
    W = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name = "W") 
    b = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name = "b") 
    learning_rate = 0.01
    training_epochs = 500
    # Hypothesis 
    y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b) 
    print('y_pred : ', y_pred)
    print('y_pred dtype : ', y_pred.dtype)
    # Mean Squared Error Cost Function 
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred-Y, 2)) / (2 * n)
    print('cost : ', cost)
    print('cost dtype: ', cost.dtype)
    # Gradient Descent Optimizer 
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)    
    # Global Variables Initializer 
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    # Starting the Tensorflow Session 
    with tf.Session() as sess: 
        # Initializing the Variables 
        sess.run(init) 
        # Iterating through all the epochs 
        for epoch in range(training_epochs): 
            # Feeding each data point into the optimizer using Feed Dictionary 
            for (_x, _y) in zip(x, y): 
                print('_x : ',_x)
                print('_y : ',_y)
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {X : _x, Y : _y}) 
            # Displaying the result after every 50 epochs 
            if (epoch + 1) % 50 == 0: 
                # Calculating the cost a every epoch 
                c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {X : x, Y : y}) 
                print('c : ', c)
                print('c dtype : ', c.dtype)
                print("Epoch", (epoch + 1), ": cost =", c, "W =", sess.run(W), "b =", sess.run(b)) 
        # Storing necessary values to be used outside the Session 
        training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict ={X: x, Y: y}) 
        print('training_cost : ', training_cost)
        print('training_cost dtype : ', training_cost.dtype)
        weight = sess.run(W)
        print('weight : ', weight)
        print('weight : ', weight.dtype)
        bias = sess.run(b)
        print('bias : ', bias)
        print('biad dtype : ', bias.dtype)
    # Calculating the predictions 
    green_light_duration_new = weight * x + bias 
    print("Training cost =", training_cost, "Weight =", weight, "bias =", bias, '\n')
    # Plotting the Results 
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label ='Original data') 
    plt.plot(x, green_light_duration_new, label ='Fitted line') 
    plt.title('Linear Regression Result') 
    plt.legend() 
    plt.show() 
    return green_light_duration_new

# Go to the training function
new_green_dur = green_light_duration_new(current_reward, current_green)

# Append the predicted green light to its list
current_green.append(new_green_dur)

# Go on to run the rest of the simulation with the new green light duration,
# and append its subsequent reward to current_reward list to run again later.
```

**UPDATE WITH PICTURES FROM BELOW SOLUTION**
With the solution provided below, it's only plotting one data point, not the three I input, and there's no line of best fit, and the axis coordinates on the bottom of the 2nd plot are not reflective of where the one data point truly is.

Also, when you `print(current_green)` at the very end after the concat'ing, the array is just 3 zeros? Shouldn't it be 4? The first inputted 3 and then the latest predicted one?

I don't understand what's happening here. Why scale the data? What I want is to be able to feed this regressor with a new list of X values (the rewards) from previous runs and have it return/predict the best possible green light duration between 10 and 120 seconds, in the same scale as it went in. After that, it should add that duration to the `current_green` list. Thanks a lot, I'm still new. The plotting is a nice feature, but it's not entirely necessary, I just wanted to see that it was working how it was supposed to.

[image: Plot Screen 1]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two error first please use MinMaxScaler to scale your data. During calculations when number go out of range NAN pops up
2. Append doesnt work in numpy array.

Here's complete solutions to your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import warnings
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

warnings.simplefilter(action='once', category=FutureWarning) # future warnings annoy me

# add in a couple of rewards and light durations
current_reward = [[-1000,-900,-950]]
current_green = [[10,12,12]]

current_reward = np.array(current_reward)
current_green = np.array(current_green)





scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(current_reward)
current_reward= scaler.transform(current_reward)

scaler.fit(current_green)
current_green=scaler.transform(current_green)

# Pass in reward and green_light
def green_light_duration_new(current_reward, current_green):
    # Predicting the best light duration based on previous rewards.
    # predict the best duration based on previous step's reward value, using simple linear regression model
    x = current_reward
    y = current_green
    n = len(x)




    # Plot of Training Data  
    plt.scatter(x, y) 
    plt.xlabel('Reward') 
    plt.ylabel('Green Light Duration') 
    plt.title("Training Data") 
    plt.show() 

    X = tf.placeholder("float") 
    Y = tf.placeholder("float") 
    W = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name = "W") 
    b = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name = "b") 
    learning_rate = 0.01
    training_epochs = 500
    # Hypothesis 
    y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b) 
    print('y_pred : ', y_pred)
    print('y_pred dtype : ', y_pred.dtype)
    # Mean Squared Error Cost Function 
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred-Y, 2)) / (2 * n)
    print('cost : ', cost)
    print('cost dtype: ', cost.dtype)
    # Gradient Descent Optimizer 
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)    
    # Global Variables Initializer 
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    # Starting the Tensorflow Session 
    with tf.Session() as sess: 
        # Initializing the Variables 
        sess.run(init) 
        # Iterating through all the epochs 
        for epoch in range(training_epochs): 
            # Feeding each data point into the optimizer using Feed Dictionary 
            for (_x, _y) in zip(x, y): 
                print('_x : ',_x)
                print('_y : ',_y)
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {X : _x, Y : _y}) 
            # Displaying the result after every 50 epochs 
            if (epoch + 1) % 50 == 0: 
                # Calculating the cost a every epoch 
                c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {X : x, Y : y}) 
                print('c : ', c)
                print('c dtype : ', c.dtype)
                print("Epoch", (epoch + 1), ": cost =", c, "W =", sess.run(W), "b =", sess.run(b)) 
        # Storing necessary values to be used outside the Session 
        training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict ={X: x, Y: y}) 
        print('training_cost : ', training_cost)
        print('training_cost dtype : ', training_cost.dtype)
        weight = sess.run(W)
        print('weight : ', weight)
        print('weight : ', weight.dtype)
        bias = sess.run(b)
        print('bias : ', bias)
        print('biad dtype : ', bias.dtype)
    # Calculating the predictions 
    green_light_duration_new = weight * x + bias 
    print("Training cost =", training_cost, "Weight =", weight, "bias =", bias, '\n')
    # Plotting the Results 
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label ='Original data') 
    plt.plot(x, green_light_duration_new, label ='Fitted line') 
    plt.title('Linear Regression Result') 
    plt.legend() 
    plt.show() 
    return green_light_duration_new

# Go to the training function
new_green_dur = green_light_duration_new(current_reward, current_green)

# Append the predicted green light to its list
np.concatenate((current_green, new_green_dur))
#current_green.append(new_green_dur)

# Go on to run the rest of the simulation with the new green light duration,
# and append its subsequent reward to current_reward list to run again later.
```

Comment: I tried running your solution, but it's still not "working" the way I'm looking for at least. Check out my update above and let me know what you think! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm marking this as complete, but it steered me in the direction of this example that I made work for my purposes. Thanks! https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression